# How to use add & remove Javascript on Table row

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have the following codes. table filter value

filter value can hide by use "display: none" and show value by "display: display:table-row"

**Problem:** I want to change ways "display: none" and "display: table-row " to add() table row when checked box and remove() table row  when checkbox empty

Can anyone advise with my codes?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xh9m5kjv/

```js
function filter(event, filterCol) {
  let element = event.target;
  let condt1 = document.getElementsByClassName(filterCol);
  for (let i = 0; i < condt1.length; i++) {
    if (condt1[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() == element.value.toLowerCase()) {
      if (element.checked == true) {
      //condt1[i].parentElement.closest('tr').add() ??????
         condt1[i].parentElement.closest('tr').style = "display:table-row"
                  
      } else {
       //condt1[i].parentElement.closest('tr').remove() ??????
         condt1[i].parentElement.closest('tr').style = "display:none"
      }
    }
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll('.option1')
  .forEach(input => input.addEventListener('input', ()=>filter(event,"check1")));
```

```html
<div id="input">
  <label>Hide 1 :<input class="option1" type="checkbox" value="1" checked/></label>
</div>


<table id="listingTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="check1">1</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="check1">2</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="check1">1</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Sorry for my bad English, can't explain all what I need, hope you understand what I need

Thanks !

Comment: As the name suggests, and the [documentation (and the examples)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) tells you, `.classList` is a collection of CSS classes. Therefor `.add()` adds such a class. Create a class for hiding, and `.add()`/.`remove()` that class (or the easier option `.toggle()`) - [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Ah!!! I Ask wrong Not Classlist I need edit My Question Thanks for advise !

Comment: Your edit doesn't make sense. There's no `.add()` method on DOM nodes. And `.remove()` would remove the node (the `<tr>`) from the DOM completely.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this code?

```
<script>
function filter(event, filterCol) {
  let element = event.target;
  let condt1 = document.getElementsByClassName(filterCol);
  for (let i = 0; i < condt1.length; i++) {
    if (condt1[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() == element.value.toLowerCase()) {
      if (element.checked == true) {
        condt1[i].parentElement.classList.remove("hide");
        condt1[i].parentElement.classList.add("show");        
      } else {
        condt1[i].parentElement.classList.remove("show");
        condt1[i].parentElement.classList.add("hide");
      }
    }
  }
}

document.querySelector('.option1').addEventListener('input', ()=>filter(event,"check1"));
</script>


<style>
.show {
  display: table-row;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Why `.hide` and `.show`? One of them should be the default state and therefor doesn't need an extra class.